Encouraging sparsity at block level or element-wise level?
I have an objective function $f(W)$, where $W$ is a $Kp \times Kp$ matrix. We can view $W$ is a $p \times p$ block matrix, where each block has the dimension $K \times K$. Now to optimize $f(W)$, I also add a term to encourage sparsity of $W$.
A naive way is to say $f(W)+\lambda ||W||_1$, where $||W||_1$ denotes the sum of absolute value of all entries of $W$. But the problem is that in this way, what we are really doing is to encourage all elements of $W$ to be $0$. What I really want is to encourage the sparsity at the block level. I am a little bit confused here. I don't know there's any difference.
But if I use $ W_{ij}$ to denote each block matrix, $i,j=1,2,...,p$. Then some alternative way could be
$$f(W)+\lambda \sum\limits_{i=1}^p \sum\limits_{j=1}^p||W_{ij}||_F$$ or
$$f(W)+\lambda \sum\limits_{i=1}^p \sum\limits_{j=1}^p||W_{ij}||_1$$
I have three forms here. Which one is to encourage the sparsity at the block level?
